# How to open a href linked to a div with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

Lets say I have a div with the id="element" the content of this div is a pop up it works for me if I open it with  but I do not know how I would aachieve the same effect with a javascript. And I need to do it that way cause it only opens up if the result of some code is false

Comment: I basically managed to open it with a link I am not really that into javascript but I know java i tried with things like click() trigger() but it did not do the job for me

Comment: I am gonna try to explain more on how it should work I have a few links leading to some content because the content is added not all links work and it should display a popup telling that I manage to trigger the popup through a link but not through my javascript but the script works since I can do an alert that but it looks ugly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you have the following div :

```
<div id="element" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');"></div>
```

Pure DOM click :

```
 document.getElementById("element").click();
```

Using jQuery :

```
$("#element").click();
```

And here is the snipped with 2 divs with different id's for you :

```js
document.getElementById("element").click();
$("#element1").click();
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="element" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');"></div>
<div id="element1" onclick="window.open('http://google.com', '_blank');"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is:

```
var win = window.open();
win.document.write(document.getElementById('element'));
```

So basically, you open  window and set its content by the content in your `div` tag.

To adjust size and other specification of the popup window, you will find ample of articles and posts.

Or if I have misunderstood and you want to open the link that is in the content of `div` then:

```
window.open(document.getElementById('element'));
```